# Should models hold references to other models?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to build a WPF application using the MVVM pattern. It would be my first one.

In my database I have 2 tables a reports table and a columns table. Basically I just want to store the skeleton of reports by storing the name and some minor infos (header row...) and save all columns in the other table.

I am wondering what would be the best approach when creating my model:

- should I do 2 models (Report and Column) for each table? And make an observable collection of Columns
- Only 1 model and create a POCO Column with a regular list of Columns

If I go with the 2 models approach should I implement 2 modelViews or can I group everything in one modelview as I will work with only one report in the view (like the edit report view)?

Hope I was able to clearly explain my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do each separately (i.e. one View/ViewModel/Model per table).  You can refactor common items later (and/or as you're building).

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels in MVVM usually have one-to-one relationship to View, unlike Asp.Net MVC. In order to decide how many Views/ViewModels you need you can start thinking of the interface. ViewModels is modeled UI, so if you have one screen in your app then you should start with one viewModel class, later you can refine it if it will be too big. Models are a little bit different, it depends how are you going to interact with them. I'm not sure what are you going to do with them, I had an experience of storing a report definition in database and it may happen that you do not really need two tables at all, you do not even need relational database, just save a blob with serialized XML. But anyway after deserializing it back to your object you will have at least two model classes - Column and Report, model is kind of lowest level of abstraction, if you won't have those two model classes you won't be able to distinguish these entities.